# Python MySQL On Mac OS X Lion

Tags: python, mysql, macos

Is there a new way to connect to MySQL from Python with Mac OS X Lion (10.7.x)?

All the material I can find only seems to support Snow Leopard (10.6) and older.

I've tried installing pyodbc, but can't get the odbc drivers to register with the operating system (maybe a 10.6 -> 10.7 compatibility issue?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the newest MySql_python worked great.  just had to run `sudo python setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

If you have `macports` installed, try:

```
sudo port install py27-mysql
```

and use the MySQLdb package instead of `pypdbc`.